# Why does `n1 if eval("n1<=n2") else n2` always return `n1`?

Tags: python, eval

I'm trying to write a function `smaller_num(n1, n2)` which returns the smaller value of two parameters. In the snippet below, although I expect the function to return `"16"`, actually `"1500"` is returned for some reason. What's wrong with the logic?

```
def smaller_num(n1, n2):
    return  n1 if eval("n1<=n2") else n2
print(smaller_num("1500", "16"))
```

Comment: Replacing `"n1<=n2"` by `"{}<={}".format(n1, n2)` works. Since `"n1<=n2"` is a string literal, variable names inside it are not replaced by the values of the variables by design. And because generally a non-empty string is converted to `True`, `n1` is always returned in your algorithm. (I don't understand why you wrap the numbers by string though.)

Comment: `1500` is greater than `16`, but `"1500"` and `"16"` are strings, not numbers. Strings are compared lexicographically.

Comment: Why are you even using `eval` at all? If you want to write a function to return the smaller of two inputs, you don't need `eval` for that. `return min(n1, n2)` or `return n1 if n1 < n2 else n2` would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of `eval()` is redundant. Try simply

```py
def smaller_num(n1, n2):
    return  n1 if n1<=n2 else n2
```

It's now clear that

```py
print(smaller_num("1500", "16"))
```

amounts to

```py
"1500"<="16"
```

i.e. you are really comparing strings. This is done lexicographically (i.e. according to their position in the ASCII/Unicode table), character by character. So though the first character are the same (`"1"` and `"1"`), the second character (`"5"` vs. `"6"`) is not "smaller or equal" for the first variable. The remaining two characters (`"00"`) are disregarded, as the other string has run out of characters. An equivalent comparison is then `"15"<="16"`, which also happens to be equivalent to `15<=16` as integers appear consecutively on the ASCII/Unicode table.

To do what you want, just use

```py
print(smaller_num(1500, 16))
```

You may even keep your original `eval()` in `smaller_num()`, though I don't see the point.